# linprog not provided in Octave although optim package installed

Tags: octave, linear-programming

I try to use Octave's [optim package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/) as a replacement (as far as possible) for Matlab. I installed both distros [Octave *MinGW*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20MinGW%20installer/) and [Octave *MSVC*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/).

`pkg install parallel-2.2.0.tar.gz` gives me the following error in case of using the *MSVC* version `sh.exe: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.
So I tried the *MinGW* version. After installing [all packages](http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php) ([general](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/general-1.3.4.tar.gz?download), [struct](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/struct-1.0.10.tar.gz?download), [miscellaneous](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/miscellaneous-1.2.0.tar.gz?download), [parallel](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/parallel-2.2.0.tar.gz?download) and [optim](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/optim-1.3.0.tar.gz?download)) being required and typing `help linprog` I ended up with:

```
error: help: Octave does not currently provide linprog.  Linear programming problems
may be solved using `glpk'.  Try `help glpk' for more info.

Please read `http://www.octave.org/missing.html' to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
```

What needs to be done to use this function as documented [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/function/linprog.html)?

## Update1

I tried [version 3.8.1](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/) as suggested by *carandraug* but the installation of `parallel` will abort with `sclose.cc:37:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory`. I may add another update after fixing this. By the way I hope the Octave developer will choose an Eclipse IDE as the default Developer-GUI in the future so something that many, many people can contribute to without starting from scratch.

## Update2

The above linked packages are newer than those being shipped with Octave 8.3.1 so I simply switched to the `src` folder and ran `build_packages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just posted this answer on a separate question:

The problem is that you didn't load the optim package. When you type `pkg list` you can find which ones are loaded by an asterisk in front of their names. Load a package with `pkg load optim`.

Having to load a packages is that thing that many users coming from Matlab find strange but if you compare with other languages, such as Python, Perl, or C++, would you expect them to `import`, `use`, or `#include` every libraries available in the system by default? See [Octave's FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error) for more details.

If you want a package to be loaded automatically by default, the recommended action is to add the line `pkg load optim` to your `~/.octaverc` file.

Finally, you have just started with Octave, you should probably have installed Octave 3.8.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction! I thought the error is connected to installation issues so I went through this [article](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows) and simply ignored the pkg load part in every *Manual installation instructions for the Octave-forge packages* section. I think the error message is misleading. Something like *optim found but not loaded yet* would fit better. Anyway thanks for detailed answer and not just stating *rtfm man!*

Comment: @dkeck the error message is not really misleading. The function really is undefined at that moment. Octave does not know what functions are in a package until you actually load it. In Octave 3.8.1, you will get an error message like that but only for some packages and functions, which are a bit more official and have been hardcoded (althoug that no Octave package is part of the Octave project yet).